# How to Filter the Table Values based upon a What-If Parameter Value in Power BI

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a table and a **What if Parameter Slicer** as shown in the image below,

[image]

What I want to do is make the Slicer interact with the Table, that is, if the Slicer value is **greater than any of the Total Sales value of any customer**, then that customer should be filtered out from the table.

How do I make sure of this?
I tried to add a Visual Filter on the Total Sales Column and tried to do this, **Filter out all the values where Total Sales < Slicer Value**, but it also didn't work for me. As it doesn't allow me to add "Slicer Value" attribute in the Visual Filter.

You can download the related Workbook from here: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15x7m3nXdlRgHdPBxOGqrJRVYYX8hEgLp/view?usp=sharing

Why I am doing this using a What-If Parameter and not by simply **adding Sales Column as Slicer**, is because I want to use the value of this slicer to create additional measures. That is something I can't do with Sales Column

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have a solution for you! Instead of using column , You need to create a measure first using this DAX Code:

```
Total Sales = CALCULATE(
    SUM(transactions[sales_amount]),
    transactions[sales_amount] >= SELECTEDVALUE('Sales Amount Filter'[Sales Amount Filter]))
```

Then If we test it on the same visual:

[image: FERD]

I hope This is what you want to have in the end!